# Spring Boot does not honor @WebServlet

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-boot, servlet-3.0, embedded-tomcat-8

I created a Servlet (extending from HttpServlet) and annotated as per 3.0 specs with

```
@WebServlet(name="DelegateServiceExporter", urlPatterns={"/remoting/DelegateService"})
```

My `@Configuration` class in Spring Boot scans this servlet's package. However, it does not log that it has deployed this servlet in the embedded Tomcat 8.0.15 container when my Spring Boot application starts up.

So, I added `@Component` to my servlet as well.  Now, Spring Boot registers the servlet (proving to me that the scan package was correctly set up), but then it registers it with a URL pattern based on a class name using camel case.  So, that was better - e.g., I got a servlet registered, but with the wrong URL mappings!

```
2015-01-05 11:29:08,516 INFO  (localhost-startStop-1) [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean] Mapping servlet: 'delegateServiceExporterServlet' to [/delegateServiceExporterServlet/]
```

How do I get Spring Boot to auto-load all `@WebServlet` annotated servlets and honor their url mappings?

Comment: You don't. Spring Boot uses a different way of configuring and mapping servlets.

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2290) to discuss the possibility of honouring `@WebServlet`.

Comment: I got it working with the advice here.  Thanks everyone!  I could not find where Spring Boot documentation says it does not support WebServlet annotation, so that is why I was confused.  If I missed the doc, please let me know where it is written.  Otherwise, at least an update to the Spring Boot documentation would be helpful - e.g., explicitly say WebServlet annotation is not supported. :)

Answer (score 47):

Add `@ServletComponentScan` in your bootstrap class.

such as

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ServletComponentScan 
public class Application {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
   }
}
```

This will enable spring boot to scan `@WebServlet` as well as `@WebListener`.

Comment: That should be the accepted answer. You're the best!

Comment: (AT)WebServlet is a JEE annotation; thus, it is only picked up when (AT)ServletComponentScan is specified. The latter is an instruction to scan for JEE annotations.

Comment: I recommend specifying (a) Java package(s) to avoid scanning the entire dependency tree; e.g., @ServletComponentScan("org.my.project.servlet")

Answer (score 7):

With Spring Boot, you should use the `ServletRegistrationBean` object instead of the `@WebServlet` annotation if you want to register a Servlet and provide the URL pattern.

Adding this bean to your `@Configuration` class should do the trick :

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean delegateServiceExporterServlet() {
    return new ServletRegistrationBean(new DelegateServiceExporter(), "/remoting/DelegateService");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to load servlets annotated with `@WebServlet` and their mappings in Spring Boot. To do this you need to use `@ServletComponentScan` with `@Configuration` annotation. This also works for `@WebFilter` and `@WebListener` annotations.